# Understanding XDebug Trace Output for bizarre memory consumed by a script

Tags: php, memory, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

What is happening is that at random times, a webpage throws "Allowed memory exhausted" error in apache logs. I have the xdebug trace of both the times, when the issue occurs and when it runs normally. When I am comparing the trace files, its surprising to see log entries without any function name and random amount of memory consumed by them. So, there are two things I want to understand.

1. I have below code

   ```
       if (function_exists('ini_set')) {
               ini_set('include_path', ROOT . DS . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));
       }
   ```

In case of error, its tracing log is as

```
2       23      0       0.007218        701448  function_exists 0      app/webroot/index.php  101    1       'ini_set'

2       23      1       0.007236        701448

2       24      0       0.007255        701592  ini_get 0              app/webroot/index.php  102    1       'include_path'

2       24      1       0.007277        701648

2       25      0       0.007288        701592  ini_set 0              app/webroot/index.php  102  

2       'include_path'  'httpdocs/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php'

2       25      1       0.007617        702016

2       26      0       0.008726        755816  include 1       lib/Cake/bootstrap.php app/webroot/index.php  104    0
```

This log has two entries for Function Id 25 that is ini_set(), with memories as 701592 and 702016. Memory consumed by first entry is 702016-701592 = 424 Bytes, and memory consumed by second entry is 755816-702016 = 53800 Bytes.

I can not understand the existence of the second entry without any function Name and where exactly is the memory by the second entry is getting used?

2. Second issue is that in two logs that I have, I can notice that memory consumed by the log entry that is without any function name greatly varies.

Below is the log for another run. Here again are two entries for function Id 25 with memories as 645616 and 646040. Memory consumed by first entry is 646040-645616 = 424 Bytes (Same as earlier), and memory consumed by second entry is 646176-646040 = 136 Bytes (in last run it was 53800 Bytes).

Again, where is it getting used and why does this amount vary! I can see many such deviations in these two trace logs summing up to an extent causing "Allowed memory exhausted" error. Please help me understand this.

```
2       23      0       0.000908        645472  function_exists 0      app/webroot/index.php  101    1       'ini_set'

2       23      1       0.000924        645472

2       24      0       0.000936        645616  ini_get 0              app/webroot/index.php  102    1       'include_path'

2       24      1       0.000952        645672

2       25      0       0.000960        645616  ini_set 0              app/webroot/index.php  102    2       'include_path'  'lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php'

2       25      1       0.000996        646040

2       26      0       0.001034        646176  include 1       lib/Cake/bootstrap.php app/webroot/index.php  104    0
```